# Character to empty in Delphi6

Tags: delphi, char, delphi-6

How can I set the specified character by index to empty character in Delphi6?

```
procedure TMainForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i: integer;
s_ord_account : String[10];
begin
   s_ord_account := '0930002930' ;
   i := 1;
REPEAT
   IF s_ord_account[i] = '0' THEN
    s_ord_account[i] := '';
  INC(i);
  UNTIL (i=5) OR (s_ord_account[i] <> ' ');
 MessageDlg(s_ord_account,mtError, mbOKCancel, 0);

yend;
```

When I try to execute this code I get an error

> [Error] Main.pas(30): Incompatible types: 'Char' and 'String'

Comment: There is no empty char! A char *always* has a value. You can set a char value that you treat as whitespace like `#32` or `' '` or maybe `#0`. `''` is an *empty string* and no char.

Comment: Empty string would mean deleting/removing the char, perhaps you'd like a whitespace char as @SirRufo suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it would make a lot of sense for you to stop using Turbo Pascal strings and use the native Delphi string type, `string`.

There is no such thing as an empty character. You can use the [`Delete`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Delete) function to remove a character from the string. A simpler approach would be to use the [`StringReplace`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StringReplace) function. That renders your code entirely needless.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

var
  s: string;

begin
  s := StringReplace('0930002930', '0', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
  Writeln(s);
end.
```

**Output**

```
93293
```

Comment: FastCoders [AnsiStringReplace](http://fastcode.sourceforge.net) is a faster alternative, incorporated into later Delphi versions.